# Caching data (image, rss) with django

Tags: django, caching

That's my first question in here, I've been looking through old questions, but nothing matched with my problem. Here it is.

I'm creating some site with one main functionality. We want this site to display content of other sites, but in a specific way. User chooses let's say two pages from five and want to see their content. He clicks button 'Display' and goes to next page where he finds let's say view from web cam, and here comes problem.

I want to cache image that is hidden behind the url from which image was downloaded, so after refresh image won't be downloaded again, but browser will get it from cache.

I've been looking through documentation of Django, but nothing seemed to be useful.

I know that I should: 
1) create table which stores cache 
2) add to settings.py some CACHE_BACKEND = ... 
3) use @cache_page(300) before declaration of function which returns content which should be cached, 
but... it doesn't seem to work.

I will be greateful if someone tells how to solve that problem, maybe with some sort of code showing the mechanism.

Cheers, 
Chris.

Answer (score 1):

I think that right way to do this will be to store image somewhere on your server and delete it later with cron or something similar.

Django cache framework wasn't created for the purpose you are trying to use it.